# How to show default size image in Jssor Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I have implemented Jssor Slider in one of my project. But the images placed in the slider are not shown with default size, rather they are shown with zoom effect.

Website of the slider is http://www.jssor.com

I used the option with value 4 to solve the problem

$FillMode -     The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, default value is 0

But its not working. Do you know any other way to show images with default size ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

'$FillMode: 4' should work. See [different size image slider](http://www.jssor.com/examples-jquery/different-size-images-slider.source.html)

May I see your example?